# Input field for decimal property

Tags: visualforce, decimal

My VF tags:

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Sales Price</apex:facet>
    <apex:inputText value="{!prod.SalesPrice}"/>    
</apex:column>
```

Controller code:

```
public string SalesPrice{get; set;}
oli.UnitPrice =decimal.valueOf(pi.SalesPrice);
```

It works when a user insert 15 and 15.00 but it doesn´t with 15,00(comma).

I m using `apex:inputText` linked to a controller apex property because `apex:inputfield` is not allowed.

I´ve tried with `apex:input` with `type=number` but it doesn´t look good, (small button to increase/decrease inserted value). Is there another `Visualforce tag` that i can use with a property? Is the only solution to replace comma with dot in the controller?

Comment: Shouldn't this depend on user locale ?  As far as I know comma as decimal separator works if your user is configured with such settings.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, problem for me is that with commas fails with decimal.valueOf conversion; and i can´t use directly OpportunityLine Item field  (unitprice )in my visual force page.

Comment: as you've probably figured out, `apex:inputText` transmits a string as typed to the controller field's setter and then you are stuck parsing this. As an alternative consider binding your VF field via inputField to some proxy Sobject with field of type Number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are simply assigning to the `UnitPrice` field on `OpportunityLineItem` you could instead expose the `OpportunityLineItem` record to the controller and use `apex:inputField` to bind directly to the `UnitPrice` field.

In your controller:

```
public OpportunityLineItem oli { get; set; }
```

Then in your Visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!oli.UnitPrice}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
You can use standard html tag and parse using JS and pass on to Controller.

Comment: Thanks but i ve already tried with it. It s in the question description.

Comment: @Enry i would suggest you an option to invoke the javascript first and then the controller method, during your submission(using ActionFunction). In the javascript, collect the SalesPrice text boxes and remove comma using regex (replace method ). You can collect the Salesprice text boxes easily by using a custom styleClass for the apex:inputText and use getElementsByClassName.